# Redirección en RequestMapping springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, spring-security

tengo un problema con la redirección en mi RequestMapping que honestamente no logro entender.
mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registro")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UsuarioControlador {
    private UsuarioServicio usuarioServicio;

    @ModelAttribute("usuario")
    public UsuarioRegistroDto retornaNuevousuarioDto() {
        return new UsuarioRegistroDto();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String mostrarFormularioDeRegistro() {
        return "registro";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String registrarCuentaDeUsuario(@ModelAttribute("usuario") UsuarioRegistroDto registroDto) {
        usuarioServicio.guardaUsuario(registroDto);
        return "redirect:/registro?exito";
    }
}
```

cuando corro el código funciona correctamente ya que al ir a la dirección:
http://localhost:8080
puedo acceder a esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo cual es accesible así ya que estoy usando spingSecurity.

sin embargo cuando intento acceder a http://localhost:8080/registro sigo accediendo a la misma pantalla y no puedo ver el archivo html que hice. alguien me puede ayudar a saber que esta pasando por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar agregando un objeto `RedirectAttributes` como parámetro.

Además de agregar un valor a tu query parameter, exito, porque a reserva de lo que puedas comentar, no le veo sentido a tener un parámetro sin un valor.

```
@PostMapping
    public String registrarCuentaDeUsuario(
        @ModelAttribute("usuario") final UsuarioRegistroDto registroDto,
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        
        usuarioServicio.guardaUsuario(registroDto);
        
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("exito", true); //por ejemplo

        return "redirect:/registro";
    }
```

El ejemplo sería más o menos así.

Edit: Agrego link a la javadoc de la clase `RedirectAttributes` que contiene un ejemplo https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).